# Javascript toggle on css navbar

Tags: javascript, button, toggle, hide

Hy! I'd like to use this simple code but it doesn't work. There are two more JS script below, can they interfere with each other? Thank in advance.

```
<nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>-->

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#"> <span title="Home">Home</span>  </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Curriculum"> <span title="About">CV</span> </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Competenze"> <span title="Competenze">Competenze</span></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#Work"> <span title="#Work">Lavori</span> </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#Contatti"> <span title="Contact">Contatti</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>   

<div class="hamburger" >
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
        <span id="navbs1" class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span id="navbs2" class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span id="navbs3" class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>            
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByid("mySidenav");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: replace `getElementsByid` with `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typo here:

```
var x = document.getElementsByid("mySidenav");
```

It should be:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="myFunction()">×</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#"> <span title="Home">Home</span>  </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Curriculum"> <span title="About">CV</span> </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#Competenze"> <span title="Competenze">Competenze</span></a></li>
        <li> <a href="#Work"> <span title="#Work">Lavori</span> </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#Contatti"> <span title="Contact">Contatti</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>   

<div class="hamburger" >
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
        <span id="navbs1" class="icon-bar">|</span>
        <span id="navbs2" class="icon-bar">|</span>
        <span id="navbs3" class="icon-bar">|</span>
    </button>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `var x = document.getElementById("mySidenav");` it's working for me, please provide more details about the error(s) you're facing. Which browser are you using? What does the console show?

Comment: i changed it but it doesn't work..maybe because of external css?

Comment: I don't think it's the css. Please open Developer Tools on Firefox: press F12, a window should open. If not, press CTRL + SHIFT + I (uppercase i). Then look for a tab named "Console": that is the JavaScript console and any error/warning will be logged there. Refresh your page and look if there are any line into the Console. Read more about the Developer Tools here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools